# Could the birthday paradox be interpreted also about deaths?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, mathematical-modeling, paradoxes

Is the probability from the birthday paradox also true about deaths? If so, why? Or why not? I would think that it is also true about deaths, but it doesn't say so.

Comment: Mathematically, yes, though in the "real world" it depends how you state the problem, and what external factors you take account of. But it should be the case, that if you somehow choose at random a group of more that $23$ dead people, the probability  of two or more of them having died on the same day of the year (though not necessarily the same year) will be more that 5$0\%$. However, this does not take account of seasonal factors- maybe people are more likely to die in winter, for example, which might skew things a little.

Comment: I suspect that births are less uniform than deaths.  For example, in many countries there are relatively few births on weekends or holidays because elective caesarians and induced deliveries are not scheduled then.

Comment: As already answered yes, it could, but notice that the deaths need not be the same year, just as the birthdays.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I studied Markov chains that perhaps could model births and deaths processes, but I couldn't take for granted that they are distributed same way. For example: If an asteroid destroys earth on a particular day and everybody dies the same day, then I suppose that it would make a difference.

Comment: The actual situation was that I mentioned the birthday paradox, and a guy said that he went to a funeral and noticed a graveyard where 3/10 deaths where the same date and I think it's perhaps not an instance of the birthday/death probability but rather an instance of locality in time and space, or some other explanation. So I could look at statistics from tombstones for real data about what we spoke about, if we can take the probability from the birthday paradox and expect it to say something about tombstone and graveyard dates in the real world.

Comment: The word that describes two problems who are the same except for superficial differences (like names, labeling) is isomorphic : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isomorphic.html

Comment: That is a interesting point about spatial location. A local epidemic, or large work accident (or natural disaster) could skew things badly, You can presumably take account of this in your definition of "random" samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an urn containing $n$ labeled balls, let $p_k$ be the probability that $k$ balls chosen at random (with replacement) contains a repeated ball.

The [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says that, when $n=365$, we have $p_k>0.5$ whenever $k \geq 23$ (the "paradox" is that $23$ seems surprisingly low).

The Birthday Paradox is often phrased in terms of birthdays since it makes it easier to communicate.  It could be death-days without any mathematical problems (or any $23$ randomly chosen dates).

In practice, however, the Birthday Paradox runs into complications (e.g. twins) which will make observations unsatisfying (and presumably deaths are not entirely independent).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the fact that if you select 23 people at random, there is a 50% probability
that at least one pair of these people will die on the same day of the year
(under the usual assumptions of only 365 days in the year and equal probability of
dying on any given day).

Aside from being a bit morbid, if you select your random sample from among the living population, you may have to wait quite a while to find out whether any two of them die
on the same day of the year. With birthdays you can find out very quickly if any two
are the same.

But those are not mathematical concerns. The math is, in fact, the same for both problems.
You can even imagine that you are rolling 23 dice that each have 365 numbered sides 
(and are equally likely to land on any of those sides) and you want the probability
that you will roll at least one matching pair.